# why does upstart start on not work as expected

Tags: linux, upstart

i have two upstart scripts, and i want the second one to start after the first

this is what i have in the second one (dir/second):

```
start on (started runlevel [345] and dir/first)
stop on (stopped dir/first or runlevel [0126])
```

*fyi both scripts are in /etc/init/dir/ directory.*
i used these two links as references: http://jurjenbokma.com/ApprenticesNotes/ubuntu_upstart.html and http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

-- issue 1

and when i start the first one with

```
initctl start dir/first
```

**the second one does not start!**

-- issue 2

also, i am able to start the second one with

```
 initctl start dir/second
```

**even if the first one is stopped!**

so why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your conditions are incorrect. `runlevel []` is an event, and `started <job name>` is an event, so your conditions should be:

```
start on runlevel [345] and started dir/first
stop on stopped dir/first or runlevel [0126]
```